# How to set zustand state in a class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-state-management, zustand

I am working on a site that has a piece a global state stored in a file using [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand). I need to be able to set that state in a class component. I am able to set the state in a functional component using hooks but I'm wondering if there is a way to use zustand with class components.

I've created a sandbox for this issue if that's helpful:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-darkness-0ttzd

here I'm setting state in a functional component:

```
function MyFunction() {
  const { setPink } = useStore();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setPink}>Set State Function</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

my state is stored here:

```
export const useStore = create((set) => ({
  isPink: false,
  setPink: () => set((state) => ({ isPink: !state.isPink }))
}));
```

how can I set state here in a class componet?:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={
            {
              /* setPink */
            }
          }
        >
          Set State Class
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

A class component's closest analog to a hook is the higher order component (HOC) pattern. Let's translate the hook `useStore` into the HOC `withStore`.

```
const withStore = BaseComponent => props => {
  const store = useStore();
  return <BaseComponent {...props} store={store} />;
};
```

We can access the store as a prop in any class component wrapped in `withStore`.

```
class BaseMyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { setPink } = this.props.store;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={setPink}>
          Set State Class
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const MyClass = withStore(BaseMyClass);
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems that it uses hooks, so in class you can work with the instance:

```
import { useStore } from "./store";

class MyClass extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            useStore.setState({ isPink: true });
          }}
        >
          Set State Class
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit gracious-frost-9vdu3]

Answer (score 4):

This worked out pretty well for me.
:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useStore } from "./store";

class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={
              useStore.getState().setPink() // <-- Changed code
          }
        >
          Set State Class
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyClass;
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a React Context provider that both functional and class-based components can consume. Move the `useStore` hook/state to the context Provider.

store.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import create from "zustand";

export const ZustandContext = createContext({
  isPink: false,
  setPink: () => {}
});

export const useStore = create((set) => ({
  isPink: false,
  setPink: () => set((state) => ({ isPink: !state.isPink }))
}));

export const ZustandProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { isPink, setPink } = useStore();

  return (
    <ZustandContext.Provider
      value={{
        isPink,
        setPink
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ZustandContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

index.js

Wrap your application with the `ZustandProvider` component.

```
...
import { ZustandProvider } from "./store";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ZustandProvider>
      <App />
    </ZustandProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Consume the `ZustandContext` context in both components

MyFunction.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ZustandContext } from './store';

function MyFunction() {
  const { setPink } = useContext(ZustandContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setPink}>Set State Function</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

MyClass.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ZustandContext } from './store';

class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={this.context.setPink}
        >
          Set State Class
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyClass.contextType = ZustandContext;
```

Swap in the new `ZustandContext` in `App` instead of using the `useStore` hook directly.

```
import { useContext} from 'react';
import "./styles.css";
import MyClass from "./MyClass";
import MyFunction from "./MyFunction";
import { ZustandContext } from './store';

export default function App() {
  const { isPink } = useContext(ZustandContext);

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: isPink ? "pink" : "teal"
      }}
    >
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <MyClass />
      <MyFunction />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-set-zustand-state-in-a-class-component]

If you aren't able to set any specific context on the `MyClass` component you can use the `ZustandContext.Consumer` to provide the `setPink` callback as a prop.

```
<ZustandContext.Consumer>
  {({ setPink }) => <MyClass setPink={setPink} />}
</ZustandContext.Consumer>
```

MyClass

```
<button onClick={this.props.setPink}>Set State Class</button>
```

Comment: This completely defeats using Zustand. It's supposed to have little boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I like to create a high order component similar to redux connect:

```
function connectZustand(useStore, selector) {
    return (Component) =>
        React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Component ref={ref} {...props} {...useStore(selector, shallow)} />);
}
```

eg:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import create from 'zustand';
import shallow from 'zustand/shallow';

function connectZustand(useStore, selector) {
    return (Component) =>
        React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Component ref={ref} {...props} {...useStore(selector, shallow)} />);
}

const useStore = create((set) => ({
    isPink: false,
    setPink: () => set((state) => ({ isPink: !state.isPink })),
}));

class MyClass extends Component {
    render() {
        const { setPink } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => setPink()}>Set State Class</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const MyClassWithZustand = connectZustand(useStore, (state) => ({ setPink: state.setPink }))(MyClass);

export default function Test() {
    const isPink = useStore((state) => state.isPink);
    return (
        <>
            <MyClassWithZustand />
            {isPink ? 'Is Pink' : 'Is Not Pink'}
        </>
    );
}
```